# Convert a string of comma-separated bytes ie "255,0,45" to a hex string in shell?

Tags: string, shell

In shell, if I were to have a string variable `"255,0,45"`, how could I convert it to hex so that it would have value `"ff002d"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have your number set as

```
n=255
```

you can get the 2-digit-hex-representation by

```
nhex=`printf %02x $n`
```

This should work in most shells. If you happen to use Zsh, there is an alternative which doesn't even require a child process:

```
((nhex = [##16] n))
```

Comment: I have n=“255,0,32”. Is it possible to get each value (255, 0, and 32) and convert them into their hex equivalent?

Comment: Sure. You need to split this string into the individual parts and then apply one of the methods I have outlined.  For breaking up the string, you still didn't say which shell you are using, but have a look at the `cut` command - this can be applied everywhere. Another possibility would be to turn the string into an array. If you number-triple is stored in n, you get the array in bash and Zsh by `a=( $(tr , ' ' <<<$n) )`. The 1st element would then be `${a[0]}` in bash and `$a[1]` in Zsh.